# Using Entity Framework, how to create a query which will fetch the column names of all tables from a database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ienumerable, generic-list

How to create a dynamic select query in C# using Entity Framework which will fetch all the column names from a SQL database. Here, the table names to be supplied in the query are fetched from a generic list of type `IEnumerable<string>`

There's a list `mylist` where index [0] has the table name `Store`, at index [1] there is a table `Address` and at [2] there is a table `Country`. Now, the query needs to be fired to database to find out what all column names are there are for `Store`, `Address` and `Country` table.

I assume, the final query should be put in the below manner--

```
select    
    mylist[0].1stcolumnname,
    mylist[0].2ndcolumnname,
    .....,
    mylist[1].1stcolumnname,
    mylist[1].2ndcolumnname, ....,
    mylist[2].1stcolumnname,
    mylist[2].2ndcolumnname, 
    .... 
from 
    SOMETABLENAME WITH JOINS"
```

If these results are fetched correctly, then final output query to be fired would look something like

```
Select 
    "Store.id", "Store.Name", "Store.gstno", "Store.addressId",  
    "Address.addressId", "Address.addressLine1", "Address.addressLine2", 
    "Address.postcode", "Address.countryId", 
    "Country.countryId", "Country.name"
from 
    SOMETABLENAME WITH JOINS;
```

As you can see here, each table name with each column name is fetched and the query is created.

Comment: If you use EntityFramework and raw SQL queries in a same project - you probably doing something wrong

Comment: No. Actually, I have to use entity framework to fetch column names of tables from a generic list and put them in a list so that it can be indexed to create a dynamic select sql query, like the one I mentioned in my question

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by _"dynamic select sql query"_, but the sample from your question can be queried if EF Core with: `var allSotresWithAddressesAndCountriesIncluded = dbContext.Stores.Include(s => s.Address).ThenInclude(a => a.Country).ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one:

```
   using (var db = new EFDemoContext())
            {
                var columnNames = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>(" SELECT T.name + '.' + C.name AS Name
           FROM   sys.objects AS T
           JOIN sys.columns AS C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
           JOIN sys.types AS P ON C.system_type_id = P.system_type_id
           WHERE  T.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'  and T.name not like  N'%sysdiagrams%';").ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Not Working, the list should have values like tablename.columnname , so that If I fetch index of the list the output should be store.id at [0], store.Name [1] and so on

Comment: you can change your select and use every columns you need, I edit my answer  try again.

Comment: I have a DB view also in database, it is fetching the colums from the view also. How to exclude the view ? I have a view named GetMetaData. Also, additional columns are fetched like sysdiagrams.definition,sysdiagrams.diagram_id,sysdiagrams.name,sysdiagrams.principal_id,sysdiagrams.version

Comment: This time the view is not fetched but still I'm getting these columns ```sysdiagrams.definition
sysdiagrams.diagram_id
sysdiagrams.name
sysdiagrams.principal_id
sysdiagrams.version```

Comment: Yes, I want only the column names of tables that reside in database. No views and no sysdiagrams tables required. Like I have store, address and country table in my Db. So only those columns should be fetched.

Comment: @ Rahul Dev I change my code and I hope it useful, try again.

Comment: No Luck. Still same output. Sysdiagrams are fetched.

Comment: you can add this (and T.name not like  N'%sysdiagrams%' ) to clause, I change it.

Comment: I tried debugging with the code you sent ```"Select  pp.nam from ( select CASE WHEN b.TABLE_NAME is not null then 'view' else 'table' end  OBJECT_TYPE,a.TABLE_NAME + '.' + a.COLUMN_NAME as nam from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS b ON a.TABLE_CATALOG = b.TABLE_CATALOG AND a.TABLE_SCHEMA = b.TABLE_SCHEMA AND a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME) as pp where OBJECT_TYPE<> N'view'"``` But I'm getting two different results. While I debug in visual studio I'm getting the desired output but when i run it as a query in SSMS i get systables data also.